# NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Tags: apache-spark

I know this question has been answered many times, but I tried everything and I do not come to a solution. I have the following code which raises a NotSerializableException

```
val ids : Seq[Long] = ...
ids.foreach{ id =>
 sc.sequenceFile("file", classOf[LongWritable], classOf[MyWritable]).lookup(new LongWritable(id))
}
```

With the following exception

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
Serialization stack:
...
org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
```

When creating the SparkContext, I do

```
val sparkConfig = new SparkConf().setAppName("...").setMaster("...")
sparkConfig.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
sparkConfig.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[BitString[_]], classOf[MinimalBitString], classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable]))
sparkConfig.set("spark.kryoserializer.classesToRegister", "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable,org.apache.hadoop.io.Text,org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable")
```

and looking at the environment tab, I can see these entries. However, I do not understand why

1. the Kryo serializer does not seem to be used (the stack does not mention Kryo)
2. LongWritable is not serialized.

I'm using Apache Spark v. 1.5.1

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I try to lookup certain keys in a sequence file. The keys are passed to the method; for the purpose of the example I just generated them randomly.

Comment: Why won't you convert it to a regular rdd and then lookup?

Comment: Good point! It doesn't affect performance? I try to really quickly get the value to a key, and I have to do this for ~5K keys out of ~10M entries.

Comment: performance-wise I'm not sure.

Comment: See [SPARK-2421](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2421). Regarding performance loading the same file all over again is pretty much as bad as you can get :) Moreover with 5K entries out of 10M you probably touch almost all partitions anyway so simple filter could be better choice.

Comment: One more thing - for an efficient lookup you need a partitioner. Without it, it is simply a linear search over all partitions.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! On your second comment: Given 5K keys I lookup, the chance is pretty high that every partition has to be considered, right? Alternatively I would have to create thousands of partitions...

Comment: Is you MyWritable class is serializable ?
Have you implemented Serializable Interface to your MyWritable class.

Comment: @navige More partitions is not a good choice either.  To large number compared to dataset size can significantly degrade performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Loading repeatedly the same data inside a loop is extremely inefficient. If you perform actions against the same data load it once and cache:

   ```
   val rdd = sc
     .sequenceFile("file", classOf[LongWritable], classOf[MyWritable])

   rdd.cache()
   ```
2. **Spark doesn't consider Hadoop Writables to be serializable. There is an open JIRA ([SPARK-2421](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2421)) for this. To handle `LongWritables` simple `get` should be enough**:

   ```
   rdd.map{case (k, v) => k.get()}
   ```

   Regarding your custom class it is your responsibility to deal with this problem.
3. Effective lookup requires a partitoned RDD. Otherwise it has to search every partition in your RDD.

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner

   val numPartitions: Int = ???
   val partitioned = rdd.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(numPartitions))
   ```
4. Generally speaking RDDs are not designed for random access. Even with defined partitioner `lookup` has to linearly search candidate partition. With 5000 uniformly distributed keys and 10M objects in an RDD it most likely means a repeated search over a whole RDD. You have few options to avoid that:

   - filter

     ```
     val idsSet = sc.broadcast(ids.toSet)
     rdd.filter{case (k, v) => idsSet.value.contains(k)}
     ```
   - join

     ```
     val idsRdd = sc.parallelize(ids).map((_, null)) 
     idsRdd.join(rdd).map{case (k, (_, v)) => (k, v)}
     ```
   - [`IndexedRDD`](https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd) - it doesn't like a particularly active project though
5. With 10M entries you'll probably be better with searching locally in memory than using Spark. For a larger data you should consider using a proper key-value store.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I integrated LevelDB into my application using now both LevelDB and Spark and I could reduce the query time massively! I also experimented with IndexedRDD, which works pretty well if the data should all be kept in memory, which I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to apache spark but tried to solve your problem, please evaluate it, if it can help you out with the problem of serialization, it's occurring because for spark - hadoop LongWritable and other writables are not serialized.

```
val temp_rdd = sc.parallelize(ids.map(id =>
sc.sequenceFile("file", classOf[LongWritable], classOf[LongWritable]).toArray.toSeq
)).flatMap(identity)

ids.foreach(id =>temp_rdd.lookup(new LongWritable(id)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It worked fine for me.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("SparkMapReduceApp");
        
        conf.registerKryoClasses(new Class<?>[]{
            LongWritable.class,
            Text.class
        });
```